# Using set to only update a subset of write properties in a Firestore transaction

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

Is it possible to use `set` (within the context of a transaction) to create a document with some object, but only *update* it with a subset of properties?

For example, I have a use case where I'd like to create or update a document, but in the update case only certain fields should be merged. In the code below, `created` should only be written on document creation (and not on update).

I've tried `mergeFields` in `SetOptions` which I thought would only apply to the update case, but seems to apply to the write case as well and causes `created` to be omitted when creating the document.

If that's the intended behaviour of `SetOption` is there another way to achieve this?

```js
t.set(docRef, 
  {
    name: 'Alice',
    updated: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    created: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
  },
  { mergeFields: ['name', 'updated'] });
```

Node.js Admin SDK 9.2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your [transaction](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Transaction.html) will first have to read the document with [get()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Transaction.html#get) to create or update, then make a decision about what to pass to `set()` in order to make sure the document contains the correct fields.  A single `set()` cannot make this decision for you.  So, something like:

```
const snap = await t.get(docRef)
if (snap.exists) {
    t.update(docRef, ...)
}
else {
    t.create(docRef, ...)
}
```